# Why am I being redirected to my php file in this contact form?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, redirect

I have a contact form that works with ajax. Everything is ok, but when the user click on Submit button, it's redirected to the php file instead of stay in the page and show the success or error messages. On the top of the contact form is a  element where I want to show the messages.

This is the contact form:

```
<div class="success error" id="form-messages"></div>
<form id="contact-form" action="mailer.php" method="post">
<div class="form-input mt-15">
    <label>Name</label>
    <div class="input-items default">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"
required>
        <i class="lni-user"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- form input -->
<div class="form-input mt-15">
    <label>Email</label>
    <div class="input-items default">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email"
required>
        <i class="lni-envelope"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- form input -->
<div class="form-input mt-15">
    <label>Message</label>
    <div class="input-items default">
        <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" required
</textarea>
        <i class="lni-pencil-alt"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- form input -->
<p class="form-message"></p>
<div class="form-input rounded-buttons mt-20">
    <button type="submit" class="main-btn rounded
three">Submit</button>
</div>
<!-- form input -->
</form>
```

This is the .js code:

```
$(function() {
// Get the form.
var form = $('#contact-form');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    });
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    })

    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and
your message could not be sent.');
        }
        });
    });
});
```

I was following a tutorial.

Comment: You do know `$(form).` can just be `form.` right? Once you store the jQuery function to a variable you can just use the variable.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Comment: I think it's because your HTML `textarea` tag is incorrectly formatted. Look at the end of the opening tag. It's not there.

Comment: I don't see any "php". Nothing in what you posted will do any redirection. I'm betting it's in what you didn't included, being `mailer.php` in your form's action.

Comment: I corrected that, I still have the same problem. I am not sure where the problem could be.

Answer (score 3):

Errors in your code:

```
// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr('action'),
    data: formData
});
.done(function(response) {
```

^ you have a `;` after the initial ajax statement, a syntax error, so the 'done' never gets done.

here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4pf2d501/

Comment: Stuart, wow, so simple, this worked, thanks. So, if the semicolons are put in there, the next statements will not be executed?

Comment: The `done` method is called in the "chain" of methods, after your initial `ajax` call. A semicolon will terminate the preceding staement. Please rtm (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) :)